# Creating a linear regression model and using vfold_cv() function

Tags: r

I only recently started learning R script in R studio at my university. I'm required to create a linear regression model using this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data?resource=download to predict 'price'.

This is what I've done so far:

```
## UPLOAD DATASET
AirBnB_price <- read_csv('train_2.csv')


## CONVERT CHARACTER VARIABLES TO FACTOR VARIABLES
AirBnB_price$neighbourhood <- factor(AirBnB_price$neighbourhood)
AirBnB_price$neighbourhood_group <- factor(AirBnB_price$neighbourhood_group)
AirBnB_price$room_type <- factor(AirBnB_price$room_type)


# MODELLING

## Split the dataset
AirBnB_price_split = initial_split(AirBnB_price, prop = 0.8)

AirBnB_price_train = training(AirBnB_price_split)
AirBnB_price_test = testing(AirBnB_price_split)
print(dim(AirBnB_price_train))
print(dim(AirBnB_price_test))

## Cross-validation ????

vfold_cv(AirBnB_price_train, strata = AirBnB_price_train$price)  


## Recipe


AirBnB_model_recipes_step <- recipe(price ~ ., data = AirBnB_price_train) %>%
  update_role(host_id, new_role = "Id") %>%
  step_other(neighbourhood) %>%
  step_dummy(room_type, neighbourhood_group) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_smote(price)

prepped_recipe = prep(AirBnB_model_recipes_step, training = AirBnB_price_train)

train_pre_processed = bake(prepped_recipe, AirBnB_price_train)
test_pre_processed = bake(prepped_recipe, AirBnB_price_test)

lm_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  fit(price ~ longitude + latitude + neighbourhood + neighbourhood_group + room_type, data = train_pre_processed)
```

I don't know a couple of things and could use someone's help:

- How and where to use the cross-validation function?
- I'm getting an error (See below) when I run this line, and don't know why > prepped_recipe = prep(AirBnB_model_recipes_step, training = AirBnB_price_train)

> > prepped_recipe = prep(AirBnB_model_recipes_step, training = AirBnB_price_train)
> > Error in prep(AirBnB_model_recipes_step, training = AirBnB_price_train) : could not find function "prep"

I could really use some guidance here. Thank you

Comment: I've now added the error to the question as well. It says "could not find function "prep"

Comment: did you try `recipes::prep(......)` ?

Answer (score 1):

First to answer your specific questions:

1. As @Qharr notes, the error indicates you do not have the `recipes` package attached.

You can add `library(recipes)` to your script. However, since you're using functions from several `tidymodels` packages, you may want to add the following to your script:

```
library(tidymodels)

tidymodels_prefer()
```

2. You need to assign your cross validation folds to an object so you can use them to fit models. Please note you reference the variable for stratification on its own (not by subsetting the training data).

```
AirBnB_folds <- vfold_cv(AirBnB_price_train, strata = price)
```

Instead of `fit()` you use the analagous `fit_resamples()` function.

3. A few important things you'll need to address. Your recipe will not `prep()` correctly for a few reasons. `step_normalize(all_predictors())` fails since there are non-numeric predictors. Look over the output of `glimpse(AirBnB_price)` and you'll see some variables you haven't dealt with when creating factors or in the pre-processing steps.

- `name`
- `host_name`
- `last_review`

You can choose how to handle these for your analysis. You can also change your normalize step to use `all_numeric_predictors()`, however this won't help given the last step in your recipe...

4. `step_smote` requires all data be numeric, and you'll need to be sure to attach the `themis` package as its not currently loaded with `tidymodels`.

Next, the variable used to sample data in SMOTE needs to be a factor, not numeric.

Lastly, SMOTE cannot handle missing data, so you need to impute those values or drop those observations from the data set.

Putting this all together:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(themis) # For over-sampling step

AirBnB_price <- read_csv('AB_NYC_2019.csv')

## CONVERT CHARACTER VARIABLES TO FACTOR VARIABLES
AirBnB_price$neighbourhood <- factor(AirBnB_price$neighbourhood)
AirBnB_price$neighbourhood_group <- factor(AirBnB_price$neighbourhood_group)
AirBnB_price$room_type <- factor(AirBnB_price$room_type)

# Drop unused fields and remove observations with NA
AirBnB_price <- AirBnB_price %>%
  dplyr::select(-name, -host_name, -last_review) %>%
  drop_na()

## Split the dataset
AirBnB_price_split = initial_split(AirBnB_price, prop = 0.8)

AirBnB_price_train = training(AirBnB_price_split)
AirBnB_price_test = testing(AirBnB_price_split)

print(dim(AirBnB_price_train))
#> [1] 31074    13
print(dim(AirBnB_price_test))
#> [1] 7769   13

## Cross-validation

AirBnB_folds <- vfold_cv(AirBnB_price_train, strata = price)  

## Recipe

AirBnB_model_recipes_step <- recipe(price ~ ., data = AirBnB_price_train) %>%
  update_role(host_id, new_role = "Id") %>%
  step_other(neighbourhood) %>%
  step_dummy(room_type, neighbourhood_group, neighbourhood) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_smote()

# Fit CV folds (resamples)
lm_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  fit_resamples(AirBnB_model_recipes_step, resamples = AirBnB_folds)

lm_model
#> # Resampling results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation using stratification 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>    splits               id     .metrics         .notes          
#>    <list>               <chr>  <list>           <list>          
#>  1 <split [27965/3109]> Fold01 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  2 <split [27965/3109]> Fold02 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  3 <split [27966/3108]> Fold03 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  4 <split [27966/3108]> Fold04 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  5 <split [27966/3108]> Fold05 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  6 <split [27966/3108]> Fold06 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  7 <split [27967/3107]> Fold07 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  8 <split [27968/3106]> Fold08 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#>  9 <split [27968/3106]> Fold09 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
#> 10 <split [27969/3105]> Fold10 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>